# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isAdmin')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am getting this error when i am trying to access my user data from my data base.
Can anyone help me in solving this.

This is my line of code where i am getting the error:

const menuToBeRendered = user.isAdmin ? adminMenu : userMenu;

this is my userSlice file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LIMo.png)

this is my userRoute file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TQ8B.png)

this is my store file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX8Ue.png)

Please help me in this problem

I am unable to crack the solution

Comment: The error message is indicating that `user` is null at the point `user.isAdmin` is checked.

Comment: Hi @Goutam, welcome to SO, It'll be really helpful for us to help you if you paste your code in your question instead of pasting a screenshot of it. If you'll provide a minimal demo in [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that'll be better to provide you a solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The initial `state.user.user` value *is* null

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null; // <--
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  }
});
```

Any consuming UI logic should account for this. One easy way is to use the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator `?.`.

```js
const menuToBeRendered = user?.isAdmin ? adminMenu : userMenu;
```

If `user` is not `null` or `undefined`, then the `isAdmin` property is accessed. In the above code, the initial `menuToBeRendered` value, based on the initial `user` state value, will be `userMenu`.